# how to call web api c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code to connect to an api although I'm getting the following error:

```
<Envelope>
  <Body><RESULT><SUCCESS>false</SUCCESS></RESULT>
    <Fault>
      <Request/>
      <FaultCode/>
      <FaultString>Server Error</FaultString>
      <detail>
          <error>
              <errorid>50</errorid>
              <module/>
              <class>SP.API</class>
              <method/>
          </error>
       </detail>
    </Fault>
 </Body>
</Envelope>
```

If I use the test harness using the same username and password I receive a success = true message.  Any suggestions?  Thanks,
James

```
public void Authenticate()
{
    const string xmlString = @"<Envelope><Body><Login><USERNAME>xxx</USERNAME><PASSWORD>xxx</PASSWORD></Login></Body></Envelope>";
    const string url = "http://api5.silverpop.com/XMLAPI";
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString);
    var myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    myReq.Method = "POST";
    myReq.ContentLength = xmlString.Length;
    myReq.ContentType = "application/xml";
    myReq.Accept = "application/xml";

    using (var requestStream = myReq.GetRequestStream())
    {
       requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse())
    {
        var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
        if (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
           var xmlResponse = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

When attempting to add service reference in VS I get the following error:

There was an error downloading 'http://api5.silverpop.com/XMLAPI/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://api5.silverpop.com/XMLAPI'.
The content type text/plain; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 245 bytes of the response were: 'falseServer Error50SP.API
'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

**Update**

I get the following error when trying to connect after adding it as a service reference:

could not find endpoint element with name 'http://api5.silverpop.com/XMLAPI' and contract 'SilverpopApiClientService.EngageSoapApiClientService_Interface' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.

Comment: Why aren't you just adding the webservice as a reference? You don't have to do all this manually.

Comment: when using the add service reference in VS I get an error occurred - have updated question

Comment: Did you check Silverpop's API documentation? Don't they have a section on authentication? What do the docs say about this error?

Comment: thats a very good point ;)

Comment: any suggestions to my latest update?  many thanks

Comment: The XML that you posted doesn't look like a SOAP message.  Is this a REST API, or SOAP?  If the former,  you aren't going to have much luck using service references.

Comment: (didn't get to finish my last comment): If it's a rest API have a look at the http web api client.  From the package manager (nuget) console: install-package microsoft.asp.net.webapi.client  Note that working with WebApi is going to be a little more "raw" than WCF, but if you are communicating with a REST service, it's the way to go.

Comment: Are you still working with this?

Comment: no!  shall I delete it?  Thanks for everyones comments